# Partial upgrade turned Ubuntu 20.04 to Pop! OS

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I did `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` and it stated something along the lines of the upgrade was not completely successful and asked if I wanted to do a partial upgrade or continue. I did the partial upgrade and it changed my OS to Pop! OS. How do I go back to what I previously had i.e. Ubuntu 20.04? I restored a backup but the OS is still the same.

Comment: If you add Pop OS repositories to a Ubuntu system, but don't *pin* the upgrades to the specific packages you wanted, you risk your system becoming a Pop OS one. System 76 provided warnings of that if you look (tweets & on their web site)   Upgrade tools go to later packages automatically; restoring data from backups is the normal way back, as package tools are one-way; but you could try `ppa-purge`